# Deleting Node with same data in 2 LinkedLists

Tags: java, nodes

as the title says, i want to compare 2 linked Lists ( Done and working ) and i want to delete Nodes with same values ONLY IN LIST 2 .. i wrote a code and tried it out, it works in specific cases but i can't seem to understand what's going on with it ( giving wrong outputs ). the idea i used is sticking a LinkedList at a node, comparing it with all the nodes in the other List then delete whenever it finds they are equal.

Here is the delete head code :

```
public void deleteHead() {
    if (head != null) {
        head = head.getNext();
    }
}
```

and here is the CompareTo Code :

```
public int compareTo(NodeData nd) {
    if (num == nd.getNum()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (num != nd.getNum()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the Delete method

```
public void delete(LinkedList LL) {
    Node curr = head;
    Node curr2 = LL.head;
    while (curr2 != null) { //To traverse LL when list1 is done traversing
        while (curr != null) { //traverse list1 while checking for common Nodes to delete

            if (curr2.getData().compareTo(curr.getData()) == 0) { //compare data in the Nodes
                System.out.println(curr2.getData().getNum() + " FOUND, WILL BE DELETED");
                deleteHead(); //delete the current node of list1
                curr = curr.getNext();
                break;
            }
            else if (curr2.getData().compareTo(curr.getData()) == -1 ){
                System.out.println(curr2.getData().getNum() + " Doesn't Match");}
            curr = curr.getNext(); //next node in list1
        }
        curr2 = curr2.getNext(); //next node in LL
    }
}
```

i tried with a simple output :

[Output](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2924)

Comment: it is great to have the code, but can you give an example of what is going wrong besides a link?

Comment: i just edited the if statement of compareTo, will check and reply again.

Comment: it's checking the same node twice , deleting the head ( just knew i have to make another method for the current node ) and the comment below is also an issue ( iteration ) @MartinSerrano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data of two nodes equals you're deleting the head of one of the lists instead of the current node.

Second, you should compare each element of the first with each element of the second list, the inner while loop will iterate and consume the second list, and when it's called again - there'll be nothing to iterate, so you should probably change:

```
while (curr2 != null) { //To traverse LL when list1 is done traversing
        while (curr != null) { //traverse list1 while checking for common Nodes to delete
```

to:

```
while (curr2 != null) { 
    Node curr = head; // <-- pay attention here, every loop you need to start from the beginning! 
    while (curr != null) { 
        if ... {
            delete(curr); // TODO: need to implement this method in your LinkedList class
        else {
             ...
```

Comment: so, i gotta make a new method to delete the current node, and test the code with your new sample.. but what is iterator ? i'll try right now.

@alfasin

Comment: i can't figure what you wrote, i thought my code is already traversing each element of list1 with all elements of list2 ? @alfasin

Comment: @AliKaraki the fact that you named your class `LinkedList` confused me (because [there is such a class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in Java). I adjusted the answer respectively.

Comment: Yeah it's not that default class. @alfasin

Comment: alright i wrote a code to delete a node at a specific place, but i can;t seem to follow the iterations and get the position of the node i want to delete ( it's when the nodes are found ) , do you have any idea on how to track the position ? i tried using a normal integer but its not working @alfasin

Comment: @AliKaraki see: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37099/linked-list-delete-node-function